# "Requires extended permission: read_mailbox" when I get all the conversations

Tags: spring, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I need to get all messages addressed to the user who identifies the access token. That is to get all the comments that other users have made in their posts, comments that have made in their albums. And also the messages they have received in the conversations.

I have it done as follows:

```
@Override
    public List<CommentEntity> getCommentsLaterThan(Date startDate, String accessToken) {

        List<CommentEntity> comments = new ArrayList<CommentEntity>();
        try {
            logger.debug("Call Facebook API for accessToken : " + accessToken + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_8);
            // Get Information about access token owner
            User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);

            StreamUtils.concat(
                StreamUtils.concat(
                    getAllCommentsFromPostsAfterThan(facebookClient, startDate, user),
                    getAllCommentsFromAlbumsAfterThan(facebookClient, startDate, user)
                )
                .map(comment -> facebookCommentMapper.facebookCommentToCommentEntity(comment)),
                getAllCommentsFromConversationsAfterThan(facebookClient, startDate, user)
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

            logger.debug("Total Facebook comments : " + comments.size());
        } catch (FacebookOAuthException e) {
            logger.error(e.getErrorMessage());
            throw new InvalidAccessTokenException(SocialMediaTypeEnum.FACEBOOK, accessToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GetCommentsProcessException(e);
        }
        return comments;
    }
```

The getAllCommentsFromConversationsAfterThan method is explained below:

```
private Stream<CommentEntity> getAllCommentsFromConversationsAfterThan(FacebookClient facebookClient, Date startDate, User user) {
           Connection<Conversation> conversations = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);
        return StreamUtils.asStream(conversations.iterator())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .flatMap(conversation -> {
                    Connection<Message> messages = facebookClient.fetchConnection(
                            conversation.getId() + "/messages", Message.class, Parameter.with("fields", "message,created_time,from,id"));
                    return StreamUtils.asStream(messages.iterator());
                })
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .filter(message
                        -> !message.getFrom().getId().equals(user.getId())
                && (startDate != null ? message.getCreatedTime().after(startDate) : true))
                .map(message -> facebookMessageMapper.facebookMessageToCommentEntity(message));
    }
```

I have obtained an access token through the Graph API Explorer Tool. Granting all permissions. And an exception occurs with this error message.

```
  (# 298) Requires extended permission: read_mailbox "
```

The documentation states that the read_mailbox permission is obsolete.

I'm using version 2.8. Is it possible to get the messages from the conversations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no API access to a user’s private messages any more.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to obtain a user access token with read_page_mailboxes permission. Then, you can generate the page access token.